# javascript, getting a random number result in each singular array

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

I'm not sure how to word the question and i'm still quite new at javascript.
So I've got a random quote generator that has each quote result as an array. I'd like to add in two items in the array which I've got so far but having one result be a random number generated eg "2 quote" but having 2 be randomised each time. The end result is for a browser based text game. So it could be "2 zombies attack" or "7 zombies attack." The code I have so far is:

```
var quotes = [
[x, 'Zombies attack!'],
[x, 'other creatures attack'],
['next line'],
]  


   function newQuote() {
var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (quotes.length));
document.getElementById('quote').innerHTML = quotes[randomNumber];  
}
```

Ideally need x(or i however it's going to work) to be the result of a random number between a set range, each differently each array.

Thank you
p.s I forgot to mention that not all the quotes require a number. Thats why I've done it as a double array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your goal correctly, you want to have a set of similar-ish message templates, pick one of them at some point and fill it with data, correct? There's a lot of ways to tackle this problem, depending on how varying can your templates be. For a simple case in my head where you just need to prepend a number to a string I'd do something like this:

```
var messages = [" zombies attack",
        " other creatures attack"], // define your messages
        messageIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * messages.length), // pick one of them
        numberOfMonsters = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1), // get your random number
        result = numberOfMonsters + messages[messageIndex]; // construct a resulting message

document.getElementById('quote').textContent = result;
```

If you'd rather have more complex strings where you don't necessarily add a number (or any string) to the beginning, like `["There's X things in the distance", "X things are somewhere close"]`, then I'd recommend to either come up with some sort of string formatting of your own or use a library to do that for you. [sprintf.js](https://github.com/alexei/sprintf.js) seems to be just right for that, it will let you do things like this:

```
var messages = ["%d zombies attack",
        "A boss with %d minions attacks"], // define your messages
        messageIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * messages.length), // pick one of them
        numberOfMonsters = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1), // get your random number
        result = sprintf(messages[messageIndex], numberOfMonsters) // format a final message
document.getElementById('quote').textContent = result;
```

EDIT: Your task is much more complex than what is described in the original question. You need to think about you code and data organization. You have to outline what is finite and can be enumerated (types of actions are finite: you can loot, fight, move, etc.), and what is arbitrary and dynamic (list of monsters and loot table are arbitrary, you have no idea what type and amount of monsters game designers will come up with). After you've defined your structure you can come up with some quick and dirty message composer, which takes arbitrary entities and puts them into finite amount of contexts, or something. Again, I'm sort of shooting in the dark here, but here's [an updated version of the code on plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/aTRxXNVi7U7lwi2TFuW5?p=preview).

Comment: nice! though I forgot to mention not all the quotes will need a number. So That's why I was using the double arrays. I tried it with [numberOfMonsters, 'message'] but then (because it's a click function) all the results generate the same random number. eg 8 zombies attack, *click* 8 other creatures attack. How would each array's number be different and to have it so they don't all require a number?

Comment: @user3438298, what else can there be besides a number? Could you list a set of possible messages you're trying to generate?

Comment: they want to randomly generate stats for some of the monsters. So at the moment we have a button you click and it loads a random message in a div from a pool of quotes on the java, hence the example "suddenly a zombie attacks" but they want it to me "suddenly a zombie attacks with hunger: 8, damage: 5 sanity 2" or for a chest box "1 map" "no items found" "10 gold pieces"

Answer (score 0):

I solved it to do what I want and still have the numbers different. The issue was I should have had the number generator within the quote function. Also can create multiple variables to use too for different number generators. The plan is to then integrate it with php to add content dynamically. Which I can do. Thanks Dmitry for guiding me in the right direction.

```
function newQuote() {

var MonsterOne = Math.floor((Math.random() * 14) + 0);
var MonsterTwo = Math.floor((Math.random() * 14) + 0);
var MonsterThree = Math.floor((Math.random() * 14) + 0);
var MonsterFour = Math.floor((Math.random() * 14) + 0);

    var quotes = [

['Test', MonsterOne, 'One'],
['Test', MonsterOne,'Two'],
['Test', MonsterThree, 'Three'],
[MonsterFour, 'Four'],
['Five'],

]


var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (quotes.length));
document.getElementById('quote').innerHTML = quotes[randomNumber];  
}
```